# Castle Windsor and Queuing Asynchronous Tasks

Tags: castle-windsor

I have a loop where I need to create multiple instances of a "download" class and set them to run asynchronously. I don't know how many instances of this class I will need ahead of time. This download class has dependencies that I would like to inject, therefore I do not want to use New to create them. What should I use to create them? Some sort of factory?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: yes, I should create a factory interface and register it AsFactory in windsor. Duh. sorry.